# How to get the real value in JSON format string in Objective-C？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
let jsonStr =    "[{\"data\":{\"Charge\":0.60,\"sumAmount\":11.86,\"tax\":0.0,\"withdraw\":12.46,\"deduct\":0}}]"

let resultdata = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: resultdata, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
    {
//       print(jsonArray) // use the json here

        if let tax = jsonArray.first {
            if let newtax = tax["data"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let resultTax = newtax["tax"] as? Double {
                    print(resultTax)
//                    print("resultTax")
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

In swift, I can get the tax value. The value is `0.0`.

In objective-c, I have not got the `0.0` value. I have used many API methods. The value is always `0`.

How to get the value `0.0` in Objective-c?

Comment: You haven't shown any Objective-C code, so it's pretty much impossible to tell what you're doing wrong. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you haven't provided any Objective-C code people can only guess, here is one, it may not be the cause of your issue:

It is the way you are displaying the value, the value is the **same**.

Assuming in both languages you have correctly parsed the real number and stored the result in a `Double`/`double` variable or `NSNumber` object then:

- `print(doubleVar)` in Swift produces `0.0`
- `NSLog(@"%g", doubleVar)` in Obj-C produces `0`
- `NSLog(@"%f", doubleVar)` in Obj-C produces `0.000000`
- `print(nsNumber)` in Swift produces `0`
- `NSLog(@"%@", nsNumber)` in Obj-C produces `0`

These differences are just how a floating-point value is *formatted*. There is no such floating-point value `0` distinct from `0.0` (or `4.5` distinct from `4.500` etc.)

HTH